# How to regenerate Androidmanifest.xml file after modifying the apk

Tags: android, android-manifest, apk

I have an apk , i wanted to customize it a bit by modifying the contents of the res folder, 
But how do repackage it as an apk,

i went through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360149/how-to-modify-a-pre-packaged-apk-file-on-client-side-by-user-who-is-using-my-des), but couldn't understand , how to recreate the androidmanifest.xml file.

Could anyone please help me out.

Comment: you want to modify an apk file that doesnt belongs to you.?

Comment: No, it was not created by me.

Comment: Ya sahil, the apk does not belong to me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally speaking, **You can't**. Consider the .apk the same as an executable on Windows; you need the source to make changes. If you could just edit the .apk at will to change the app, you could change every app to be your property or contain your name.

Piracy comes to mind - if you could readily change any application to appear to be written by you (copyright messages, window captions, etc.), it would make it much harder to prevent theft of someone else's app. If the app is yours (meaning you wrote it), you should have the source (meaning the Java code that makes up the app that was put into the .apk), and you can change it easily. If the app was written by someone else and you purchased it, it's not your 'property' (unless you bought the source/rights as well), and you should contact the author for change requests

However there are possible ways to decompile Java programs. You can use **dex2jar**, it provides a somewhat good start for you to start looking for things and changes. And perhaps rebuild the code by mounting back the pieces together.

you can also use tools such as **apkTool** , then if you need to change the source code you would need other tools to do that, one of them could be **jd-gui**.

You would then need to put the apk back together and sign it, if you don't have the original key used to sign the apk this means the new apk will have a different signature.

However, let me say that it's still forbidden to change programs, as I said above. And it's extremely unethical.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!  . I understand that it is unethical , but the apk in question has a small bug ,as it displays a wrong resource(png) in place of another one, so basically i just wanted to rename the png file, in the res folder. I also have dropped a mail to the developer regarding the same. I was just trying out my options :)

Comment: @sahil..did you get a chance to go through the link i have attached in the question?  Could you please explain the step no. 3 of the answer in that question .

Comment: what's not so clear about step 3.? also i have found an application to modify the apk's https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.ninjamorph.free&feature=search_result

Comment: In that Link when he says Extract apk  to a temp folder , does he mean  converting the apk to zip file then extracting, In step 2 , we modify the files and in step 3 he says modify the androidmanifestxml file, I was not clear as to how can we modify the manifest xml file ?